# Angular/MVC test if this tutorial works

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on this tutorial (Mvc,angular,using visual studios I have 2012 and 2013 if the version matters) and I have posted this question on the actual tutorial-page but I have not received a response as the author isn't encountering this issue. Basically when I download the app attach the database I can only add to my sql sever database(using 2012 express) but it is not displaying data. This code error pops up saying error(because of the alert).Can someone download and run the tutorial to see if I am doing it wrong or I am learming from a bad source

What I get http://tinypic.com/r/2yjsf9f/8

I can't work it out as I am new to this and if you see the error can you please tell me what it is as I have been stuck on it for a week and a half and have no clue thank you for any help.I will post a image of what it should look like in the comments.

```
$scope.divEmpModification = false;
GetAll();
//To Get All Records  
function GetAll() {
    var Data = angularService.getEmp();
        Data.then(function (emp) {
        $scope.employees = emp.data;
    }, function () {
        alert('Error');
    });
}
```

the tutorial and download link there is also a demo of what it should be like. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/869433/AngularJS-MVC-Repository-Dispose

Comment: Anwser :1. Go to solution -> Model1.edmx -> Model1.Context.tt -> Model1.Context.cs 
2. You should have something like:
Hide   Copy Code
public MvcAdvancedEntities()
            : base("name=MvcAdvancedEntities")
        {
            Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        }
It is an error related to entity framework which I think it is improved in the newest version